# Why Contains in .Filter(func()) is not working in gorethink and parts of query get ignored?

Tags: go, gorethink

I am trying to do this:

```
r.table(table).filter(
  function (doc) {
    return r.expr(array)
            .contains(doc("name"));
  }
)
```

written in golang that is

```
rethink.Table(table).GetAllByIndex(index, value).Filter(func(row rethink.Term) interface {}{

    return rethink.Expr([]string{}).Contains(row.Field("type"))
})
```

I am not sure but it is like rethink.Expr is ignored.
That is first problem.

Second problem is next. If I have query written like this:

```
query := rethink.Table(table).GetAllByIndex(index, value)
```

and then try to do next:

```
if some_condition {
   q.Filter(some_filter)
}

if some_other_condition {
   q.Filter(some_other_filter)
}
```

when i print out `q.String()` i got only that first part and everything else is ignored `rethink.Table(table).GetAllByIndex(index, value)`

Comment: `Filter` returns a new `Term` so to fix your second problem you need to re-assign `q` like so: `q = q.Filter(some_filter) ...`.

Comment: @mkopriva add this as answer. You saved my day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [Filter](https://godoc.org/github.com/GoRethink/gorethink#Term.Filter) method returns a new [Term](https://godoc.org/github.com/GoRethink/gorethink#Term), which will contain the expression of the previous term, you need to re-assing the result back to `q`.

```
if some_condition {
   q = q.Filter(some_filter)
}

if some_other_condition {
   q = q.Filter(some_other_filter)
}
```